# Shouldn't wrapped optionals always print with the keyword 'Optional'?

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

#### Code

```
func downloadimages (URL: NSURL) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest ( URL: URL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error ) in

        guard error == nil else {

            print("we have an error from Server")
            return
        }
        var JSONData: AnyObject!
        do {

            JSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) /* as? [String:AnyObject?] */

        } catch {
            print (" We had a Parsing issue '\(data)'")
            return
        }
            print(JSONData)// Doesn't print 'Optional' word?????
            print(JSONData!)
        if let something = JSONData!["photos"]{

            print (something!)
            print(something) // This prints the word 'Optional as well'

        }
```

#### Output

```
//printed unwrapped--NOT GOOD! -- I didn't unwrap it with '!'
    {
        photos =     {
            page = 1;
            pages = 622374;
            perpage = 1;
            photo =         (
                            {
                    farm = 8;
                    id = 27765969370;
                    isfamily = 0;
                    isfriend = 0;
                    ispublic = 1;
                    owner = "8262787@N07";
                    secret = 6daeee7d68;
                    server = 7233;
                    title = "Stars, Planets and Lightning Bugs";
                }
            );
            total = 622374;
        };
        stat = ok;
    }
    // unwrapped printed--Good!
        {
            photos =     {
                page = 1;
                pages = 622374;
                perpage = 1;
                photo =         (
                                {
                        farm = 8;
                        id = 27765969370;
                        isfamily = 0;
                        isfriend = 0;
                        ispublic = 1;
                        owner = "8262787@N07";
                        secret = 6daeee7d68;
                        server = 7233;
                        title = "Stars, Planets and Lightning Bugs";
                    }
                );
                total = 622374;
            };
            stat = ok;
        }

   //Unwrapped printed--Good
    {
        page = 1;
        pages = 622374;
        perpage = 1;
        photo =     (
                    {
                farm = 8;
                id = 27765969370;
                isfamily = 0;
                isfriend = 0;
                ispublic = 1;
                owner = "8262787@N07";
                secret = 6daeee7d68;
                server = 7233;
                title = "Stars, Planets and Lightning Bugs";
            }
        );
        total = 622374;
    }

//wrapped and prints as optional--Good!
        Optional({
            page = 1;
            pages = 622374;
            perpage = 1;
            photo =     (
                        {
                    farm = 8;
                    id = 27765969370;
                    isfamily = 0;
                    isfriend = 0;
                    ispublic = 1;
                    owner = "8262787@N07";
                    secret = 6daeee7d68;
                    server = 7233;
                    title = "Stars, Planets and Lightning Bugs";
                }
            );
            total = 622374;
        })
```

My confusion is, if JSONData is an optional then why does it print as non-optional without `!` and if it isn't an optional then why doesn't it give any error as `Can not force unwrap value of non-optional type?`. Since unwrapping a non-optional is error-ful!

My guess is that I am not understanding what my `JSONData`'s type really is...

Comment: `JSONData` is  `non-optional` because it's type `AnyObject!`,but when you call a  `subscript` of it ,likes `AnyObject[xxx]` it will give you a optional type

Comment: @WilsonXJ I see your point that if some object is non-optional, it doesn't mean that its subscripts should also be optional. Is it that Dictionary/Array subscripts are always optionals?

Comment: @WilsonXJ even if I unwrap the optional, it still prints using the keyword 'optional'. Why does it happen that way? I have tried `JSONData!["photos"]! and still it prints with Optional.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24876897/5175709)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My guess is that I am not understanding what my JSONData's type really is...*

I believe that is the point.
You've declared `JSONData` as `AnyObject!`, which is also known as `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<AnyObject>`.

So, in your code `print(JSONData)`, the value of `JSONData` is implicitly unwrapped.

And check the type of `something` in the Quick Help pane of your Xcode. It should be displayed as `AnyObject?`, aka `Optional<AnyObject>`.

One bad thing is that when implicit unwrapping occurs it doesn't get well-documented. You may need to know more about `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`, before knowing exactly when that happens.

Comment: OK, but why doesn't it give an error? I mean isn't JSONData once already unwrapped? Can you unwrap an unwrapped value once more?

Comment: Unwrapping is not something changing the state of the content. Implicit unwrapping occurs at every point where you use `JSONData` without explicit unwrapping.

Comment: hmmm. What exactly is explicit unwrapping then? I *think* I know what implicit unwrapping is...

Comment: Explicit unwrapping -- postfix `!`, generates a code which tests the value is nil or not, and crash the app if it's nil. It also tells the compiler that the value is not Optional.

Comment: Doesn't the implicit unwrapping do exactly the same? Can you please elaborate on their differences? ASFAIK it's that you can do implicit unwrapping during *declaration* however explicit unwrapping is during *definition*.

Comment: Implicit unwrapping do exactly the same thing **without `!` operator**. The postfix `!` in the type part of declarations are just telling the compiler that "this type is `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` so you -- compiler -- need implicitly unwrapping", it does not do actual "implicit unwrapping" during declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116295/discussion-between-honey-and-ooper).